# Graphs with $p$ nodes and $k$ neighbors.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Consider the number of graphs with $p$ nodes and exactly $k$ neighbors per node. Show that the $\log$ of this number is upper bounded by $pk\log(pe/k)$.

I'm not completely sure how to do this problem.

Comment: Is $e$ the number of edges?   It would improve the Question to edit it with this identification of variables.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you share what you've tried, and explain what you're having trouble with? Do you have any theorems or background results that might be helpful?

Comment: @hardmath It is $e$ (the mathematical constant). I really don't understand the problem at all.

Comment: @RobertMingHao $e$ will pop up when trying to upper bound $\binom{p}{k}$: namely, $\binom{p}{k}\leq \left(\frac{pe}{k}\right)^k$ for any $1\leq k \leq p$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's bound the number $n(p,k)$ of such graphs. Note that such a graph is only chosen up to a permutation (I assume the graphs are unlabeled), so we actually must divide the number (or upper bound) we get by $p!$. (I.e., any two graphs that are identical up to relabeling of the nodes (permutation) are acually the same graph.)

For any of the $p$ nodes, we have to choose a subset of $k$ neighbors among the other $p-1$  nodes: there are $\binom{p-1}{k} \leq \binom{p}{k}$ ways of choosing such a subset.

Thus, we get a bound
$$n(p,k) \leq \frac{1}{p!}\binom{p}{k}^p\leq \binom{p}{k}^p.$$

Taking the logarithm and using [known upper bounds for Binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas), we get
$$
\ln n(p,k) \leq p \ln \binom{p}{k} \leq p \ln \left(\left(\frac{pe}{k}\right)^k\right)
= pk \ln \frac{pe}{k}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

[This similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77730/how-many-p-regular-graphs-with-n-vertices-are-there) doesn't exactly answer yours, but gives some related results for labeled graphs. Your question isn't specific enough anyway. Are you referring to simple graphs or multigraphs, labeled or unlabeled?